# Solving an N-port in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have an N-Port which I want to derive the equivalent Z matrix, where N = 2 is the number of ports in this instance. So, for example,

```
P = Z * U
```

Where `P` and `U` are 2x1 vectors and `Z` is a 2x2 matrix.

I've applied conditions for `P` and measured `U` for two different cases. Ex:

case 1: `P = [1; -1]`, resulting `U = [u11; u21]`

case 2: `P = [-1; 1]`, resulting `U = [u12; u22]`

Now I want to solve for what the `Z` matrix

```
Z = [Z11 Z12; Z21 Z22]
```

using my known values. In other words, I'd like to know how I can use MATLAB to solve for the components of `Z` in terms of the components of `U` and `P`. (i.e. a symbolic solution not a numeric one). I'd also like to know how to expand this since I may have a number of ports.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well in the `N=2` case you have 2 equations in 4 unknowns, so you have 2 free variables, so say let `Z12=s` and `Z22=t` then

```
Z11=(P1-s*u2)/u1
```

and

```
Z21=(P2-t*u2)/u1.
```

This is easily generalised to arbitrary `N`. You will have `N*(N-1)` free variables, so `Z12`, `Z13`,...,`Z1N`,`Z22`,...,`Z2N`,...,`ZN2`,...,`ZNN` are all free, and then, for each `i=1,2,...,N`,

[image]

Comment: I'll revise my initial post because it's not completely clear. Let's say we run two simulations with P_A = [1; -1] and P_B = [1; 1]. Measurements are then performed and we find values for U_A and U_B. These are two linearly independent cases, each case containing two equations. (Total 4 equations, 4 unknowns) We should then be able to solve for P = Z*U for the elements of Z.